# How to initialize code modules in workers

Tags: factory, web-worker

I'm a big step further in my attempt to make an image decoder from nodes usable in the browser. the code already works in the program just like its node version. but if that were my goal to only use it in the program, I wouldn't have needed to bring it locally into my program from nodes. I just tested it to see if it works and it does and that was a huge step.
my goal is to be able to use the decoder in workers. I have seen in another decoder that works with workers that the decoder is integrated via a factory function. maybe you are now wondering why i don't use the decoder that works with workers???
the reason is that said decoder can only read 8-bit images. fast-png can read 16 bit images and that's exactly what i need.

but I'm not very familiar with embedding code in factory functions. I have never tried this in connection with imports and therefore my first question:
can factory functions be used at all in connection with import?
if so, I'm obviously doing something wrong, because it doesn't work.
can anyone show me an example of how to do it correctly?

If it is helpful I can also create a repository on github.

```
(function(global, factory){
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
    (global = typeof globalThis !== 'undefined' ? globalThis : global || self, factory(global.png = {}));
})(function (exports) {


import {IOBuffer} from '../resources/libs/fast-png/IOBuffer.js';
import { inflate, Inflate as Inflator } from '../resources/libs/fast-png/pako.js';
import {pngSignature, crc} from '../resources/libs/fast-png/common.js';
import {ColorType, CompressionMethod, FilterMethod, InterlaceMethod} from '../resources/libs/fast-png/internalTypes.js';

class PngDecoder extends IOBuffer {
    constructor(data, options = {}) {
        super(data);    

        //many parameters, I have deleted them here so that 
        //there are not hundreds of lines of code here and the essentials are not lost
    }//end constructor
    
    //... many methods, i deleted them to keep track
}//end class

//...
//... many functions, i deleted them to keep track
//...


function decodePng(data, options) {
    const decoder = new PngDecoder(data, options);
    return decoder.decode();
}


exports.decodePng = decodePng;

}));//end of factory function



async function imageLoader() {
    
    const arrayBuffer = await(await fetch('./resources/textures/depth1.png')).arrayBuffer();
    
    const imageData = await png.decodePng(arrayBuffer);
    const data = imageData.data;

    postMessage(data);
}

//will call when the worker is called
imageLoader();
```

Comment: Please use better tags, at least tag your question with the programming language and the libraries/frameworks you are using. It it unlikely anyone is following just the "factory" and "web-worker" tags since those are both so vague in meaning. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging